# AFNetworking doesn't seem to send Authorization Header with AFJSONRequestOperation

Tags: header, authorization, afnetworking

I'm trying to send an Authorization header using AFNetworking and AFJSONRequestOperation. If I NSLog the httpClient after setAuthorizationHeaderWithToken, it'll show that it's in the header, but when I check the server it's sending to, it doesn't seem to receive the Authorization header (it receives the other parts).

Does AFJSONRequestOperation do something with the header where it's not adding the Authorization part?

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kBaseURL];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/" parameters:params];   

[httpClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithToken:@"test"];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = nil;

operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation
             JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
             success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

             }
             failure:^(NSURLRequest *request , NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error , id JSON ){

             }];

[operation start];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding the header before creating the `NSMutableURLRequest` (which in this block of code doesn't seem to need to be mutable) with the httpClient? It looks like you're not adding the token header until after you're creating the request in which case the AFJSONRequestOperation never even sees the header, since really in the [source code](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFHTTPClient.m#L397-399) of `AFHTTPClient` that function is just a convenience method for adding an HTTP header with the name "Authorization"

Comment: +1 Header has to be set before creating `NSMutableURLRequest` object.